# Too many unexplained GET request from server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, firewall, web-server

I have a debian server with plesk panel, this server is used for a wordpress mu installation with 10k blogs, from apache status I see a unexplained behavior, the same server send 5/10 GET continuous requests (5/10 every second) to root url of some blogs, this is example of access_log apache

> lhost.serverhost.eu - - [30/Jul/2012:22:43:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0"
>   200 49152 "-" "WordPress/2.9.2; http: subdomainblog .maindomain. it"

I must restart apache to solve the problem, but after a few minutes the problem reappears again. I verified my crontab and there is not a problem

nb: the requests are coming from himself

Answer (score 1):

While a connection is open, you can use `netstat -anp` (run as root) to see what program opened the connection.   That may help identify the where to look to find the cause.

I notice from your Apache log line that the User-Agent header of the request is WordPress.  Perhaps you have a plugin that is configured to connect back to your server?

Answer (score 0):

Are these requests always coming from the same IP? If so, just block that IP using iptables:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
```

Replace 1.2.3.4 with the IP address the requests are coming from.

Keep in mind that this rule is not persistent between reboots. You'll need to use `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` to save your rules on shutdown and reload them on boot.

Comment: I badly explained, the requests are coming from himself